# Android: click button to check existence and save file

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I want the app can achieve follow functions
1.put file name into ediTtext
2.press a start button,
   if the file exists, write into the file, if not, create the file
3.press stop button,
   the process will be stopped and the content of editText will return to the file name.

I have finished the save file part, but don't know how to check existence :P, hope can get some code for reference!
Thanks!

Here is the code for saving file:

```
        ////////////////////////////////////
private String TAG = "MyActivity";
private WifiManager wifiManager;
List<ScanResult> list;
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler handler;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_list);        
    handler=new Handler();
    runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            init();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    }; 

    handler.post(runnable);
}




private void init() {
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    list = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);     
    String wifiInfo = "";
    if (list == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "wifi is closed！", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        for (int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
            ScanResult scanResult = list.get(i);
            String bssid = scanResult.BSSID;
            String ssid = scanResult.SSID;
            int strength = Math.abs(scanResult.level);
            wifiInfo = wifiInfo + String.format("%25s,%20s,%5d\n", bssid,ssid,strength);

        }
        listView.setAdapter(new NewAdapter(this,list));
    }
    writeToFile(wifiInfo,"WifiList_Info.txt");
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "new record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}



private void writeToFile(String data,String fileName){

    File file = null;
    OutputStream output = null;
    byte buffer[] = null;   

       try{ 

        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File(path,fileName);
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();
        output = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        buffer = data.getBytes();
        output.write(buffer);
        output.flush();
        output.close();        
           } 
          catch(Exception e){              e.printStackTrace(); 
          } 
}



 public void onClick_startEvent(View view) {
     EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
     editText.setText("writing into the file", TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
}
```

}

Comment: i see you already have written code for checking file existence in you writeToFile method ... if(!file.exists()) file.createNewFile(); ... are you facing any issue with this code?

Comment: You have the answer right in your code: `file = new File(path,fileName); if(file.exists())`.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela  Now I want to write more than one files, and i can put in the file names, so i add an edittext part, which can manually put in file names, and I also add one button, when press the button, it can start to write the file, if i want to achieve this function, where i need to change? thank  you:)))

Answer (score 0):

for checking file existance use :

```
File tempFile = null;

tempFile = new File(filePath);
if(!tempFile.exists())
    //do your work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File myFile = new File(your_file_path);


if(myFile.exists())
   {

           // file exists
    }


else

{

   // file doesn't exists, so create a new file here.

}
```